# How to avoid reduction of complex fractions using SymPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm playing with SymPy and, for readability and explanation purposes, I wanted to print a fraction with the imaginary number in the denominator (Euler's formula for sin x), but every time 1/(2j) gets reduced to -0.5j, no matter what I write.

What's funny is that without the `j` the fraction doesn't get reduced.
Here's an example:

```
cosx = (sp.exp(1j * x) + sp.exp(-1j * x))/2
num = sp.exp(1j * x) - sp.exp(-1j * x)
sinx = sp.sympify(num/(sp.S(2j)), evaluate=False)
```

With `sp.pprint()` cosx is printed like I want, while sinx gives me the problem I was talking about.
As you can see I tried everything I know to avoid that, but it still gives me `-0.5*I`.
I even tried the stupid way, similar to an example in SymPy documentation:

```
sinx = sp.Mul(1, sp.Rational(num, 2j), evaluate=False)
```

but that gives me TypeError for sp.Rational

So: how do I keep that imaginary number in the denominator?